# Paging with Oracle and sql server and generic paging method

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I want to implement paging in a gridview or in an html table which I will fill using ajax. How should I write queries to support paging? For example if pagesize is 20 and when the user clicks page 3, rows between 41 and 60 must be shown on table. At first I can get all records and put them into cache but I think this is the wrong way. Because data can be very huge and data can be change from other sessions. so how can I implement this? Is there any generic way ( for all databases ) ?

Answer (score 17):

As others have suggested, you can use rownum in Oracle. It's a little tricky though and you have to nest your query twice.

For example, to paginate the query

```
select first_name from some_table order by first_name
```

you need to nest it like this

```
select first_name from
  (select rownum as rn, first_name from
    (select first_name from some_table order by first_name)
  ) where rn > 100  and rn <= 200
```

The reason for this is that rownum is determined *after* the where clause and *before* the order by clause. To see what I mean, you can query

```
select rownum,first_name from some_table order by first_name
```

and you might get

```
4   Diane
2   Norm
3   Sam
1   Woody
```

That's because oracle evaluates the where clause (none in this case), then assigns rownums, then sorts the results by first_name. You have to nest the query so it uses the  rownum assigned *after* the rows have been sorted.

The second nesting has to do with how rownum is treated in a where condition. Basically, if you query "where rownum > 100" then you get no results. It's a chicken and egg thing where it can't return any rows until it finds rownum > 100, but since it's not returning any rows it never increments rownum, so it never counts to 100. Ugh. The second level of nesting solves this. Note it must alias the rownum column at this point.

Lastly, your order by clause must make the query deterministic. For example, if you have John Doe and John Smith, and you order by first name only, then the two can switch places from one execution of the query to the next.

There are articles here http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/06-sep/o56asktom.html
and here http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/07-jan/o17asktom.html. Now that I see how long my post is, I probably should have just posted those links...

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the methods for restricting the range of rows returned by a query vary from one DBMS to another: Oracle uses ROWNUM (see ocdecio's answer), but ROWNUM won't work in SQL Server.

Perhaps you can encapsulate these differences with a function that takes a given SQL statement and first and last row numbers and generates the appropriate paginatd SQL for the target DBMS - i.e. something like:

```
sql = paginated ('select empno, ename from emp where job = ?', 101, 150)
```

which would return

```
'select * from (select v.*, ROWNUM rn from ('
 + theSql
 + ') v where rownum < 150) where rn >= 101'
```

for Oracle and something else for SQL Server.

However, note that the Oracle solution is adding a new column RN to the results that you'll need to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that both have a ROWNUM analytic Function. Use that and you'll be identical.

In Oracle it is [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm#i86310)

ROW_NUMBER

Yep, just verified that ROW_NUMBER is the same function in both.

Answer (score 1):

"Because...data can be change from other sessions."
What do you want to happen for this ?

For example, user gets the 'latest' ten rows at 10:30.

At 10:31, 3 new rows are added (so those ten being view by the user are no longer the latest).

At 10:32, the user requests then 'next' ten entries.

Do you want that new set to include those three that have been bumped from 8/9/10 down to 11/12/13 ?
If not, in Oracle you can select the data as it was at 10:30

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 as of timestamp (timestamp '2009-01-29 10:30:00');
```

You still need the row_number logic, eg

```
 select * from
    (SELECT a.*, row_number() over (order by hire_date) rn
    FROM hr.employees as of timestamp (timestamp '2009-01-29 10:30:00') a)
 where rn between 10 and 19
```

Comment: The other alternative is actually grab 100 rows at the start but only show 10 at a time. The javascript only has to hide/reveal table rows. This counts on the users never wanting to page down more than ten times.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
  from ( select /*+ FIRST_ROWS(n) */   a.*,
      ROWNUM rnum 
      from ( your_query_goes_here, 
      with order by ) a 
      where ROWNUM <= 
      :MAX_ROW_TO_FETCH ) 
where rnum  >= :MIN_ROW_TO_FETCH;
```

Step 1: your query with order by

Step 2: `select a.*, ROWNUM rnum from ()a where ROWNUM <=:MAX_ROW_TO_FETCH`

Step 3: `select * from ( ) where rnum  >= :MIN_ROW_TO_FETCH;`
put 1 in 2 and 2 in 3

Answer (score 0):

If the expected data set is huge, I'd recommend to create a temp table, a view or a snapshot (materialized view) to store the query results + a row number retrieved either using ROWNUM or ROW_NUMBER analytic function. After that you can simply query this temp storage using row number ranges.
Basically, you need to separate the actual data fetch from the paging.

Answer (score 0):

There is no uniform way to ensure paging across various RDBMS products. Oracle gives you rownum which you can use in where clause like:

```
where rownum < 1000
```

SQL Server gives you row_id( ) function which can be used similar to Oracle's rownum. However, row_id( ) isn't available before SQL Server 2005.