# What's the best method to do paging in my ASP page

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, paging

What's the best method to do paging in my ASP page when displaying a list of items?

I knew that there is no equivalent to MySQL's `LIMIT` clause present in SQL Server, either 2000 or 2005.

How can I retrieve some particular records (Records 20 to 30) from the DB?

Do i need to fetch all the records from the database and do something in my ASP page to display the required records?

Comment: @Shyju: Are you using ASP Classic or ASP.Net?

Comment: Infact it was an ASP.NET page.But i am not using a datagrid kind of control.instead i am using ajax to load contents to a div

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Whats the best method to do paging in my ASP page when displaying a list of items ?**

I just want to add one more feature to Mr. Wheat's answer. Why not u are trying to use the Take () and Skip() feature of linq(obviously if u are using dotnet framework 3.5+)

It is indeed helpful while working with large datasets.

Have  a look
[Using Take and Skip method in LINQ queries](http://www.vikramlakhotia.com/Using_Take_and_Skip_method_in_LINQ_queries.aspx)

**I knew that there is no MySQL LIMIT clause present in SQL server(both 2000 and 2005 should support).how can i retrieve some particular records (Record 20 -30) from DB ?**

You can do this in SQLSERVER 2005+ by using ranking function Row_Number() among other alternatives. A sample example is included herewith

First I am creating a dummy table and inserting some 50 records

```
declare @tbl table(name varchar(50),age int)
;with num_cte as
(   select 1 as rn
    union all
    select rn+1 from num_cte where rn<50
)  
insert @tbl
select  names ,rn + 20 ageval                
from num_cte
cross apply( select  'name' + CAST(rn as varchar(2))  AS names) names
select * from @tbl
```

Now by using the Row_Number() function I am picking up records between 20 & 30

```
select name,age from(
select ROW_NUMBER()over (order by age) as rownum,name,age from @tbl) X
where X.rownum between 20 and 30
```

However, for achieving the same in SQL SERVER 2000 the below query will help

```
select name,age from(
select t1.name,t1.age,
(select count(*)+1 from @tbl where name<>t1.name and age<=t1.age) rownum
from @tbl t1
)X(name,age,rownum)
where rownum between 20 and 30
```

Comment: actually, LINQ came in .NET 3.5 only - so you need 3.5 or up

Comment: in SQL server 2000 ,there is no row_number support .So effective server side paging is not possible .Is nt it ?

Comment: The example Imhave presented here is where rownum between 20 and 30(for the second query). As you can make out I am giving a lower & upper limit(20 & 30 respectively).i.e. I am picking up 10 records.
By using this concept, you can easily do the paging!. Hope I do make myself clear to you!(:

Answer (score 1):

Please see:

- [Paging In ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20210322122155/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/091003-1.aspx)
- [Data Access Tutorials](http://www.asp.net/Learn/data-access/)
- [GridView Examples for ASP.NET 2.0: Paging and Sorting the GridView's Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx)
- [SQL Server 2005 Paging – The Holy Grail](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/66030/)

Comment: This is an ASP Classic question, as far as I can see.

Comment: well, it's tagged sql server. It could well be, but I don't see it tagged classic ASP...

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: that's because *I* tagged it. Even if I think it's Classic, I'm not 100% sure. Only the original poster can be :)

Answer (score 0):

Youd need to use [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) (SQL Server 2005+)

```
 SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT a.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY hire_date) rn
    FROM hr.employees AS OF TIMESTAMP (TIMESTAMP '2009-01-29 10:30:00') a)
 WHERE rn BETWEEN 10 AND 19
```

<sub>[Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488108/paging-with-oracle-and-sql-server-and-generic-paging-method/489941#489941)</sub>

Using `ROW_NUMBER`, you are numering and sorting the inherently unsorted group (the table). Once you have an [ordered set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28computer_science%29) instead of just a [set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29), you can now the sentence "*I want all the rows from 10 to 19*" makes sense.

You will have to use ASP code to keep both the upper and lower elements, so you can ask for the next or previous subset of rows to show.